# Why Instantiated Remote Player Grabber won't work?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am developing a multiplayer vr game with unity using photon network. When I start the game in my main scene, the grabber works normally, but when I switch to another scene and instantiate the player, the grabber does not work, what could be the reason?

Comment: Have you tried don't destroy on load?